# c3p0 ConnectionTester: Does DATABASE_IS_INVALID cause an immediate removal of the invalid DB?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, c3p0

I see statusOnException return this DATABASE_IS_INVALID on certain exceptions, but I see nothing use this return value.

Is this just a constant that ConnectionTester uses for optional logging, but internally it will purge the database from the pool? Is the behavior configurable, if so, where?  Using JDBC driver with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `Connection` test returns `DATABASE_IS_INVALID`, [the pool is reset](https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0/blob/9f97c814aef31b2997d6ecfad1e3875c6136317b/src/java/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/impl/C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java#L567-L568), meaning all outstanding Connections will be destroyed rather than reused when they are checked back in, and the pool will reconstitute itself with fresh, new Connections.